# No output on using Semaphores

Tags: synchronization, semaphore

I wanted to use semaphores in a project but i am stuck here.I wrote three programs for printing a statement in critical region of all three programs to see how semaphores do synchronization. There is no output and the program goes in sleep state.Here is the code-

```
    int main()
    {
        int fd,ret,kk,x=1,y=2;
        struct sembuf sem[2]={{0,-1,SEM_UNDO},
            {0,1,SEM_UNDO}};
        union semun a;
        a.val=1;
        kk=semget(1234,1,IPC_CREAT);
        semctl(kk,0,SETVAL);
        semop(kk,&sem[0],1);
        printf("In client1...\n");
        printf("In client1...\n");
        sleep(3);
        semop(kk,&sem[1],1);
    }
```

I made 2 copies of this program client2 & client3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code `sem[0]` stands for "post semaphore of id=0" and `sem[1]` means "wait on semaphore of id=0". By doing

```
semctl(kk,0,SETVAL);
semop(kk,&sem[0],1);
```

you are trying to wait on semaphore with value 0. Process doing that will wait until value of semaphore is greater than 0, which in your case is never true. Doing

```
union semun semopts;
semopts.val = 1; 
semctl(kk,0,SETVAL, semopts);
```

before using semaphore first time, should fix your problem.

Comment: That will never work because the second argument is for semnum which in my case should be 0 because this is the first & only of the set. So 0 is for index.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since I used SysV semaphores last time. Of course it should be `union semun semopts; semopts.val = 1; semctl(kk,0,SETVAL, semopts);` I edited the my answer.